# Reduce the file size of .dat file

Tags: file, compression, reduce

I have a .dat file which is of 80mb I need to reduce the file size less than 10mb
Any code or method to reduce the file size

Comment: It all depends on the contents of your .dat file. Is it mostly text (or any restricted symbol set)? Is it redundant? If there are almost random data (like already compressed data) you won't have a 8 to 1 reduction with any method.

Comment: None of the existing common general purpose compression tools do the job?

Comment: @Zerte the file i have is weights of ML model(binary data) stored in .dat format, file is not compressed

Comment: Give a try with LZMA.